# How the event update API works? (MS Graph API)

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, rest

In case, I use the Event Information Update (`PATCH /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/events/{id}`) API, how is the content change (body.content) judgment made?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reaching out. Per the [update event documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) values that should be updated should be supplied in the event body. Existing properties that are not included in the request body will maintain their previous values or be recalculated based on changes to other property values. In this case, the body should change only if supplied in the request.

Let me know whether this helps and if you have further questions.